# Android AchartEngine: How to attach additional data from a different source for each plotted point in a line graph?

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm trying to make something that would allow me to press data points in a line graph. I created a subclass of GraphicalView and added a method to it, which gets called when the graph is clicked.

```
// This goes into the activity
graphicalView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    graphicalView.displaySomething();
}

// This one is from the GraphicalView subclass
public void displaySomething() {
    SeriesSelection seriesSelection = getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
    int pointIndex = seriesSelection.getPointIndex();
    double xValue = seriesSelection.getXValue());

    /*
     Now in this method, I can do some pretty cool stuff like drawing
     additional graphics near the clicked point in the line chart simply
     by redrawing the graph and passing it some data. This is made possible
     by subclassing both LineGraph and ScatterChart.

     For the purposes of this question though, I would simply log the
     values I'm curious about.
     */
     Log.d(TAG, "pointIndex: " + pointIndex + ", xValue: " + xValue);
     repaint();
}
```

Let's just say I have a graph that shows the weight of my pet dog over time and then I have an array of a list of strings which explains why my pet got that heavy, her favorite food at that time, her activites, etc. The data in the array will be displayed somewhere outside the graph (ie. to a group of TextViews). What I expect is to get the index of the clicked point, and then use that to index the array of data.

`pointIndex` and `xValue` are the variables I'm curious about. When drawing additional graphics to the graph, `pointIndex` was very helpful since ScatterChart's drawSeries knows how to use this variable properly. However, it can't be used for what I want to achieve because this value is not constant per point. For example, I have a point in the graph that lies in (5, 10) and it shows up as the fifth point with pointIndex 4 when the graph is not panned to the left. However, when I pan the graph to the left so that the mentioned point shows up as the first point, the pointIndex changes to 0. Which is why I can't use this variable to index the data array.

As with `pointIndex`, most of the values related to a point have the same behavior, but I've noticed that `xValue` is constant. I'm considering on using this value to index my external data source, perhaps by using a Map where `xValue` is the key. However, I can't figure out where to create this data structure. I've looked around achartengine's source code and it seems that the best place to do the Map's initialization is in ScatterChart's drawSeries method. The problem is the array of floats being passed to it also move around relative to the graph's panning, but my array of data does not move along with it. Can you please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. I overrided GraphicalView's onDraw method so that I can extract keys and attach them to my data. It goes something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.getClipBounds(mRect);
    int top = mRect.top;
    int left = mRect.left;
    int width = mRect.width();
    int height = mRect.height();

    if (mRenderer.isInScroll()) {
        top = 0;
        left = 0;
        width = getMeasuredWidth();
        height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    mChart.draw(canvas, left, top, width, height, mPaint);

    /*
     * This is where we build the map of <data point, info>
     */
    if (mIsFirstDraw && mIsAttachData && mAdditionalPointData != null && mAdditionalPointData.size() > 0) {
        // ClickablePoints is an interface that has a method to get the datapoints rendered by ScatterChart
        List<float[]> pointCoords = ((ClickablePoints) mChart).getDataPointCoords();
        mPointKeys = new double[pointCoords.size()];
        mAdditionalDataMap = new HashMap<Double, String>();

        for (int i = 0, j = mPointKeys.length; i < j; i++)  {
            float[] coords = pointCoords.get(i);
            SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChart.getSeriesAndPointForScreenCoordinate(
                    new Point(coords[0], coords[1]));
            mPointKeys[i] = seriesSelection.getXValue();
            mAdditionalDataMap.put(seriesSelection.getXValue(), mAdditionalPointData.get(i));
        }

        mIsFirstDraw = false;
    }
}
```

mIsFirstDraw is a flag that indicates that it is the first time that the graph will be drawn. It needs to be taken down afterwards so that it does not repeat attaching keys to the data.

Answer (score 1):

this code will allows you to click data points in achartengin:

```
mySimpleXYPlot.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // handle the click event on the chart
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mySimpleXYPlot
                        .getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                if (seriesSelection == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(Records.this, "No chart element",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // display information of the clicked point
                    Toast.makeText(
                            Records.this,
                            "Chart element in series index "
                                    + seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex()
                                    + " data point index "
                                    + seriesSelection.getPointIndex()
                                    + " was clicked"
                                    + " closest point value X="
                                    + seriesSelection.getXValue() + ", Y="
                                    + seriesSelection.getValue(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, I already know that much. My code is actually based from that example from the demo. I can click data points just fine, and I can get data about the point just fine, but I want my graph to notify my activity about the clicked point so that it can display data from another data source. The problem is I cant find a suitable value for that purpose.

Comment: you can use hashTables which you use xvalue in key and your ArrayList of texts in value.After retrieving xValue in onTouch() you get ArrayList from hashTable

Comment: Thanks. That's also what I'm planning to do, as stated in my question. But if I decide to go that way, my next problem is how to attach those xValue keys to the ArrayList values because right now, we only know how to get xValue when the user actually clicks on the datapoint. Right now, I'm looking at achartengine's source code to see if it's possible to do that (by overriding methods most probably) because it seems to me that this solution is the most viable solution.